# External Interrupt Pins on Nano Clones

Tags: arduino-nano, interrupt, clones

Long time lurker, first time poster here.

Do the cheap Arduino Nano clones [such as this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D12TWNZ) have external interrupt pins?

For example, the original Nano has pins 2 and 3 usable for interrupts. Do clones tend to incorporate this feature? If so, can anyone recommend one which does?

I'm planning on using an encoder for my next project and want to make sure I can use interrupts so my code doesn't skip over encoder counts.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I understand your doubt. In a world where Uno WiFi i not Uno it is better to ask. And the Wawgat boards which are named Uno but use a different 8-bit MCU are a trap too.

The Nano in your link has Atmega 328p and interrupts are a feature of the MCU. There is no reason for the clone manufacturer to not use the standard Nano pinout as specified in Open Hardware Nano schematics. Then the board is compatible with Arduino Nano as defined in Arduino AVR boards package.

The clones usually use a cheaper chip for USB. You will maybe need to install a driver for the CH340.

In a few days Nano Every will be available and I expect clones of it in a short time because it is a very simple board. It will use the ATmega 4809 and Arduino advertises exact pin compatibility with old Nano. But I expect in details problems similar to Uno WiFi R2 versus classic Uno problems. One of the problems could be the mapping of interrupt pins.

And later this year Nano 33 will be released. It is a Nano format board with SAMD or nRF52 MCU so 3.3 V (the 33 in name).